# Azure DevOps yaml: use a powershell task output parameter to generate a loop in dependent job

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have the following yaml as used in an Azure DevOps pipeline (this is not the full pipeline - it's just a portion of yaml that is in a template):

```html
jobs:
- job: CheckExcludedWorkspaces
  displayName: Check Excluded Workspaces
  pool:
    name: DefaultWindows
  steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      name: GetWorkspaces
      displayName: Check Excluded Workspaces
      inputs:
        filePath: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/pipelines_v2/powershell/checkExcludedWorkspaces.ps1"
        targetType: FilePath
        errorActionPreference: 'stop'
        arguments: -environmentFolder "$(rootFolderPrefix)\${{parameters.environmentFolder}}" -excludeFolderList "${{parameters.tagOutList}}"
        pwsh: false

# - ${{ each folder in dependencies.CheckExcludedWorkspaces.outputs['GetWorkspaces.WorkspaceList'] }}:
- job: NewJob
  dependsOn: CheckExcludedWorkspaces
  variables:
    testVar: $[ dependencies.CheckExcludedWorkspaces.outputs['GetWorkspaces.WorkspaceList'] ]
  pool:
      name: DefaultWindows
  steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "Test var = $(testVar)"
      displayName: Test workspaces output
```

this works correctly in that the second job retrieves a variable from a powershell task in the previous job and outputs that variable value. The task in the second job outputs a list of apps using variable testVar. The output contains:

app1,app2,app3,app4 etc

I would like to take this the next stage which is I would like to create a loop of jobs that repeated runs for this application list.  Something like:

```html
jobs:
- job: CheckExcludedWorkspaces
  displayName: Check Excluded Workspaces
  pool:
    name: DefaultWindows
  steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      name: GetWorkspaces
      displayName: Check Excluded Workspaces
      inputs:
        filePath: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/pipelines_v2/powershell/checkExcludedWorkspaces.ps1"
        targetType: FilePath
        errorActionPreference: 'stop'
        arguments: -environmentFolder "$(rootFolderPrefix)\${{parameters.environmentFolder}}" -excludeFolderList "${{parameters.tagOutList}}"
        pwsh: false

- ${{ each folder in dependencies.CheckExcludedWorkspaces.outputs['GetWorkspaces.WorkspaceList'] }}:
  - job: NewJob
    dependsOn: CheckExcludedWorkspaces
    variables:
      testVar: $[ dependencies.CheckExcludedWorkspaces.outputs['GetWorkspaces.WorkspaceList'] ]
    pool:
        name: DefaultWindows
    steps:
        - powershell: |
            Write-Host "Test var = ${{folder}}"
        displayName: Test workspaces output
```

This code gives me an error:

Unrecognized value: 'dependencies'. Located at position 1 within expression: dependencies.CheckExcludedWorkspaces.outputs['GetWorkspaces.WorkspaceList']

Is there a way i can use a powershell task output variable, to create a list of jobs in a dependent job?  The problem is that i don't know at design time what the list of applications will be (the pipeline should ideally find this out when it runs).  The list of applications is based on the list of folders that are created within a repository - which changes over time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current situation, we cannot use the 'each' key word for the variables. The 'each' keyword is used for the Obj type, but the variable is String.
For more details, you can refer the doc: [Each keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword)

Comment: understood thanks.  I'll work around this problem